# Open source PGP key server

Tags: open-source, pgp

I am looking for an open-source PGP key server for Linux. It will be run as a private server, i.e. only accessible to a limited group of users.

My google searches have turned up lots of public key servers. But the only source code I could find is [OpenPGP Public Key Server](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pks/files/) which is quite old.

Any better suggestions? I'm happy to use a bigger software package (somethign like Zimbra) if it has PGP key server support.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a bunch of open source OpenPGP key server implementations.

- The [**OpenPGP Public Key Server (PKS)**](http://pks.sourceforge.net/) based on a thesis of Mark Horrowitz is a rather old implementation, but still under active development.
- [**SKS keyserver**](https://github.com/cmars/sks-keyserver) is probably the one running most key servers at this time. There are [ready-to-use packages for eg. Ubuntu](http://www.rainydayz.org/content/installing-opensks-keyserver).
- [**Hockeypuck**](https://launchpad.net/hockeypuck) is another very recent implementation of the SKS protocol in the Go language, that uses a PostgreSQL database as backend.

SKS and Hockeypuck use a more efficient set reconciliation protocol to synchronize with each other, PKS uses a less efficient approach. Both SKS and hockeypuck can be configured to also synchronize with PKS key servers using the old protocol.

Setting up PKS is a hassle. SKS is a little bit better, especially if readily packaged in your distribution. I recently set up a hockeypuck instance and really liked it. Clean software, well documented (although rather new) and a nice relational backend which you can easily have a look, no Berkley DB or similar hard-to-query stuff.

Comment: If I understand correctly, Debian team officially provides [a package for SKS](https://packages.debian.org/buster/sks). This package is (obviously) also available in Ubuntu.

Comment: @FranklinYu I would advise **against** setting up SKS - the reason being SKS has/had some pretty major design holes that were security flaws - Ubuntu shifted to Hockeypuck a while ago because of it

Comment: This answer looks quite old and seems to be in dire need of an update to reflect recent times; Hockeypuck and Hagrid seem like they should garner more attention and/or focus. @jenserat

Answer (score 2):

Another one is [Mailvelope Key Server](https://keys.mailvelope.com). Described as *"A simple OpenPGP public key server that validates email address ownership of uploaded keys."*

License: AGPL v3.0

Comment: I would really love if this was a valid option for self-hosting, but it's clearly not intended for production use by anyone but Mailvelope themselves. Even if they do provide instructions on how to deploy their code. Not only do lots of the links and textual elements assume they are being hosted at mailvelope.com, but their master branch is almost always broken. I have been very disappointed by mailvelope.